# How to use a string that stores integer values (result of a SQL query)?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using C# and SQL Server.

I have to retrieve the prices of particular products from a table and make use of these values later for computation.

For eg.

I use the following query and store it in a string.

```
string str = " select cat_price from category where cat_itemID= 'A001'" ;
```

Now I need this particular value retrieved here to be stored in a variable for further computation

for eg.

```
int price_amount;
```

and I need to use mathematical operations. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve data from a DB? Or is this a type casting problem(i.e. converting from a string to an int)?

Comment: You need to perform math operations on the price within the query ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ExecuteScalar` method of a `SqlCommand` to get the first value:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cn, "select cat_price from category where cat_itemID= 'A001'"))
    {
        //Execute the query and just get the first result.
        int value = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.I was able to solve the problem by parsing the string.
decimal num = decimal.Parse(str);

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLDbConnection and ExecuteScaler to get get this out of the DB if that is your question.  Below is a link to do this.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx